# Php framework and BlueImp Conflict

Tags: php, frameworks, jquery-file-upload

I'm having problems with this plugin.
I think I have evertything ok, but when I look for the uploaded images there's nothing.

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    var url = HTTP+"server/php";
    //alert(url);
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: true,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        previewMaxWidth: 100,
        previewMaxHeight: 100,
        previewCrop: true,
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>')
                    .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
            if (!index) {
                node
                    .append('<br>')
            }
            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
            file = data.files[index],
            node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
        if (file.preview) {
            node
                .prepend('<br>')
                .prepend(file.preview);
        }
        if (file.error) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            data.context.find('button')
                .text('Upload')
                .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            if (file.url) {
                var link = $('<a>')
                    .attr('target', '_blank')
                    .prop('href', file.url);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .wrap(link);
            } else if (file.error) {
                var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(error);
            }
        });
    }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        });
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

I don't get any errors or warnings, the folder has the permissions. I'm working whit PHP. 
[image: No errors or warnings]

---

Note: `UploadHandler.php` execute `REQUEST_METHOD = GET`. And I have two calls for the class. Here's an image. How can I solve this?
[image: Responses]

Answer (score 0):

Should your URL not be like this?
`var url = HTTP+"server.php";`

instead of

`var url = HTTP+"server/php";`

When your image upload request is being sent, the script cannot be found and a redirection is occurring, which seems to mess up the process.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was a slash :-o `var url = HTTP+"server/php/"`